# Having trouble getting an iAd banner in a TableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I want it to appear above the tab bar at the bottom of the screen, but below the table. It seems that a tableviewcontroller makes the whole screen a table and isn't resizable.

Any ideas how to implement this iAd banner?

Comment: Any ideas what this has to do with the `xcode IDE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular `UIViewController` instead of a `UITableView` for the type of your class.
After that, add a `UITableView` to that VC, and it's delegates (you could copy those from another `UITableViewController`).

The `UITableView` is now just a subview of your `UIViewController` and you can set it's frame. You can also add another view (and use setFrame:) in which you could display the iAds...

So instead of:

`YourClass.h : UITableViewController <delegates...> {}`

You get:

```
YourClass.h : UIViewController <delegates...> {

    UITableView *tableView;
    UIView *iAdView;
}
```